# Can Build.PL be used for Enterprise Perl based application having multiple Perl Modules

Tags: perl, build-automation

If a Perl based Application has Multiple Modules >150 , ALL Custom, and related to solving particular tasks within the application, so is it possible to have Build.PL include all of these Modules, and then be able to Build, test and cover ?
I could not find any evidence where Build.PL has been used for Multiple Packages.

How do we declare these Modules in Build.PL ?

Do i have to Build and test All these Modules individually ?

Like all other languages Perl should have a builder that can handle not only building, but also testing, code coverage and deployment.

Comment: How are you installing the modules at present? Do you know that Build.pl is part of Module::Build? Have you read the docs or any tutorials for that module? Have you looked at the setup on any cpan modules with dependencies? Clarify these and I'm sure we'll be able to help.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? You mention "packages", but you might mean modules. You mention "Build.PL", but you sound like you think that that file did something all by itself. You say "Perl should have a builder" and it sounds like you think it doesn't have one. You say you couldn't find any evidence, but you don't mention where you where searching.

Comment: I am using puppet to install the modules, as well as some of the modules are being installed using MINICPAN. Its just the examples all referred to a Single Perl Module. But i have found example applications with multiple Perl Modules and also enforcing version numbers, which i will follow, and http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Build/Cookbook.html really helps, so rather than providing some examples of how to add multiple modules using Module::Build just saying yes it can be done does not help much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to have Build.PL include all of these Modules, and then be able to Build, test and cover ?

Yes.

> I could not find any evidence where Build.PL has been used for Multiple Packages.

You haven't looked very hard. A third of CPAN does so.

> How do we declare these Modules in Build.PL ?

`./Build manifest`

> Do i have to Build and test All these Modules individually ?

No, as a whole.

> Perl should have a builder that can handle not only building, but also testing, code coverage and deployment.

There are several.